# System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Items.AddRange() fails for List<DictionaryEntry>

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I receive from the external package `List<DictionaryEntry> list`.

I want to pass it to `ComboBox.Items.AddRange()` which requires `object[]`

I tried:

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
comboBox.Items.AddRange((object[])(list.ToArray()));
```

but the C# VS2013 compiler fails.

The following code based on `ComboBox.Items.Add()` works perfectly with no explicit casting `DictionaryEntry` into object.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in list)
    comboBox.Items.Add(item);
```

Due to other reasons I do not want to use the `combobox.DataSource` property where I can assign `List<DictionaryEntry> list`.

Is there any simple way with no performance burden to convert `List<DictionaryEntry>` list into `object[]`?

Comment: Are you even sure that casting to `object[]` is causing overhead? This might be micro optimization. You should run tests to see if it's really that big of a deal, which I don't think it would be, casting isn't an expensive operation. It's boxing/unboxing that's more expensive.

Comment: @AustinWBryan I meant by overhead the solutions like foreach example in my code or writing derived class from List<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using the `Cast<>()` method:

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(list.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: There is neither Cast() nor Cast<>() method available for List<DictionaryEntry> list

Comment: Add using System.Linq;

Comment: Cast method appeared but compiler still fails with : error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>' to 'object[]'

Comment: Call ToArray() on it.

Comment: Your solution works. However I tested that it is 5 times slower then my  foreach (combobox.Item.Add()) example